# How to determine the playing state and pause state in default media player?

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am using `isMusicActive` function to detect the media player is running (note that this is default media app, such as `com.sec.android.app.music`). Now, I want to determine the pause state. Is it possible to get that state? Thank all

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().AUDIO_SERVICE);
if (mAudioManager.isMusicActive())
```

Comment: You can't do this ... Obviously MediaPlayer instance is internal for given app and you can't access it ...

Comment: Thank you. So we can only detect the playing state. is it right?

Comment: I think I found the solution. The state if (!mAudioManager.isMusicActive()) is pause